# Why are my google maps marker positions all offset by about an inch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I can't say for sure what code is being use to generate this because I'm using the WP Google Maps plugin - in the backend where I set up the map the markers are in the correct position however, on the actual map the markers are all offset by about an inch (depending on screen size/resolution obviously)... Is there some sort of CSS I have that could cause this?

[image]

Here's the site if you want to take a quick look: http://coopadvertising.ca/respire/locations-contact/

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: The map isn't zooming correctly, it looks like it is off center when zooming in and out. Can you strip all of your css out and re-introduce it piece by piece to see where it breaks?

Comment: @Brett I removed all of the CSS and the markers were right.. but I have 1500 lines of CSS, is there anyway to inspect the markers so I can just see what CSS might be applying to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The markers are not offset, everything else is offset(e.g. the tiles, you also may have noticed that the copyrights and the google-logo are missing )

It's caused by these formats in   http://coopadvertising.ca/respire/wp-content/themes/sympathique/style.css :

```
.page-title .page-background {
     height: 180px;
     left: 0px;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: 0;
}

.page-title .page-background img {
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -960px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did notice that that CSS was causing it. I've changed the rule to `.page-title .page-background > img` to fix it.